# Magento 2 - Product with Multiple Options with Quantity

Tags: magento2, quantity, multiple-add-to-cart

I'm basically trying to have a product(t-shirt) with multiple sizes with its own quantity.

Like this;

[image]

Is there any extension or tutorial to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this out but its not free https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-configurable-product-grid-table-view-extension.html

Comment: Thank you, its very close. However, i would like to have more answers before deciding an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grouped product type for such functionality.

See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-grouped.html for details

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KAndy but i was hoping for the exact design which is only possible by an extension.